# How to communicate from DirectX (C++) to XAML (C#) in a "Windows Phone Direct3D with XAML" project

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have used `Visual Studio 2012` to create a new project based on the "Windows Phone Direct3D with XAML" template. I need two-way communication of variables and functions between the XAML (C#) portion and the DirectX (C++) portion.

I can communicate in the XAML->DirectX direction via the Direct3DBackground (m_d3dBackground) object, which is accessible from MainPage.xaml.cs.

**Is it possible to do this in the reverse (DirectX->XAML) direction**? Does the Direct3DBackground container have any knowledge of the XAML page it's embedded in?

**Alternatively**: As a poor man's substitute, can I set up an event on the XAML page that fires on each frame and polls for changes in Direct3DBackground's member variables?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new project, why not try the new interop model on Windows Phone 8.1. WP8.1 has adopted SwapChainBackgroundPanel and SurfaceImageSource, already available to Windows Store apps, so apps can combine DirectX graphics with XAML. This replaces the XAML and Direct3D project templates you use for Windows Phone 8 apps. For information on using XAML and Direct3D together, see [DirectX and XAML interop](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/19/whats-new-for-xaml-and-directx-interop-in-windows-8-1/).

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632424.aspx) you can get more detailed feature introduction about windows phone 8.1.